# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms, forms-authentication

I know this question has been asked before but each question has a different scenario to what I have or I am missing the obvious.

So I have implemented SSO architecture, so the user click on log in and redirected to identity server and log in there and get redirected back to the application.

in one of my application I want to use the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` in my `membershipprovider`, but it is always empty. so I found out that I need create a cookie and set it up properly to get the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` form wherever I want.

My code look like this:

After the user is redirected from the Identity server to a login control:

```
if (!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                HttpContext.Current.Session["username"].ToString(),
                DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), true, String.Empty, 
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
    string encryptedCookie = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                        encryptedCookie);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("/my-profile", true);
}
```

My web config file looks like this:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms domain="http://localhost:8081" name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" 
      protection="All" path="/" />
 </authentication>
 <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
 </authorization>
```

after the user is redirected to the my profile page the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true and the `AuthinticationType` = Cookies. but the Name is empty.

I am using asp.net webforms.

UPDATE: I have tried to set the `HttpContext.Current.User` it is set properly but when the page load or redirected it goes back to null empty.

```
  if (ticket != null && !ticket.Expired)
{
      var roles = ticket.UserData.Split(',');
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = new   System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new FormsIdentity(ticket), roles);
  }
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `domain` is wrong - in your app.config; `<forms domain="http://localhost:8081" ... />` in this context domain has a meaning of domain into which the cookie is set. You can read more about [domain of cookies here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path).

Domain is something like www.google.com or .google.com etc - it doesn't contain protocol prefix, it doesn't contain port and it makes no sense to use it for local hosts - so drop that attribute from your web.config for good.

Also (and this has nothing to do with your issue, it's just a friendly suggestion) - you don't have to construct forms auth ticket when all you care about is username.  You can use just [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk50ykcd(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.